# Why does a boolean if statement using pandas create an error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

How do I format this to be able to test with an if statement?

```
result = dfrow.str.contains('Animation')
x = 0
print(result)
if result == False:
    x = 1
if result == True:
    x = 2
```

The print function outputs:

```
1    False

Name: genres, dtype: bool
```

The error given:

```
----> 4 if result == False:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you will be using a 1 row dataframe for this scenario. Then you can use

```
dfrow.str.contains('Animation').iloc[0]
 instead of 
dfrow.str.contains('Animation')
```

Comment: Why could he  want use only the first value?

Comment: @ansev Even if we output multiple values, the next steps break as op is treating it as a singular True or False variable